# PHP documentation on method

Tags: php, wordpress, code-documentation, poedit

I'm writing some documentation on my PHP files and I am not sure what type the `$description`  variable should be in this scenario.

My guess is that it would look something like this but I am really unsure.

```
/**
 * Undocumented variable
 *
 * @method string
 */
public $description;

public function __construct() {
    $this->description = __(
        'Lorem ipsum', 'theme-option');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I do it :

```
/**
 * Undocumented variable
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $description;

public function __construct() {
    $this->description = __(
        'Lorem ipsum', 'theme-option');
}
```